# Nested callbacks in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to create an animated map.

I have points that drop on to my map that all run in a callback as so...

```
 // Animate the drops
$marker.animate({
    top : '100px'
}, 500, 'easeOutBounce', function(){
    $america.animate({
        top : '150px'
    }, 500, 'easeOutBounce', function(){
        $england.animate({
            top : '80px'
        }, 500, 'easeOutBounce', function(){
            $australia.animate({
                top : '300px'
            }, 500, 'easeOutBounce');
        });
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Liamatvenn/T3CTH/1/

Is this a bad way to go about this?  Will this take up more resources on my visitor's computers?

Comment: "Is this a bad way about this?" — that's subjective

Comment: "or will this take up more resources on my visitors computers?" — Compared to what?

Comment: @PatsyIssa Your clarification fails to actually clarify anything; "running all 4" is what happens in the current code. I think you mean "running all four simultaneously". And there's no need to insult people; it would have been enough to say "It's obvious to me that he means [...]".

Comment: @Quentin Probably compared to running all four animations simultaneously.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not a bad way to do it, but it's ugly (that's subjective) and can become hard to maintain. I'd clean it up with promise objects, manipulated with [`.promise()`](http://api.jquery.com/promise/) and [`.then()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/), to avoid the nested callbacks:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T3CTH/2/)

```
$marker.animate({
    top : '100px'
}, 500, 'easeOutBounce').promise()
.then(function(){
    return $america.animate({
        top : '150px'
    }, 500, 'easeOutBounce').promise();
})
.then(function(){
    return $england.animate({
       top : '80px'
   }, 500, 'easeOutBounce').promise();
})
.then(function(){
   return $australia.animate({
       top : '300px'
   }, 500, 'easeOutBounce').promise();
});
```

Or, you can use a [queue](http://api.jquery.com/queue/):

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T3CTH/4/)

```
var $queue = $("<div>");
$queue.queue(function(next){
    $marker.animate({
        top : '100px'
    }, 500, 'easeOutBounce',next);
}).queue(function(next){
    $america.animate({
        top : '150px'
    }, 500, 'easeOutBounce',next);
}).queue(function(next){
    $england.animate({
        top : '80px'
    }, 500, 'easeOutBounce',next);
}).queue(function(next){
    $australia.animate({
        top : '300px'
    }, 500, 'easeOutBounce',next);
}).dequeue();
```

Answer (score 6):

@KevinB already showed how to write the callback pyramid in a more convenient form. Yet, the script is still quite repetitive. Better:

```
var p = new $.Deferred().resolve();
$.each([
    [$marker, 100],
    [$america, 150],
    [$england, 80],
    [$australia, 300]
], function(_, x) {
    p = p.then(function() {
        return x[0].animate({
            top : x[1]+'px'
        }, 500, 'easeOutBounce').promise();
    });
});
```

Comment: I was just working on a similar solution. This is much better code to maintain. Well done!

Comment: It could've been written even more elegant with [`Array::reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), but unfortunately this is a [tag:jQuery] question :-)

Comment: So that others can see the elegance of this solution, I [jsfiddled it](http://jsfiddle.net/T3CTH/7). I inlined the class selectors in the fiddle so `$marker` would be `$('.marker')`, `$america` would be `$('.america')`, etc. Other than that, it is all the same.

Comment: See [this fiddle version](http://jsfiddle.net/T3CTH/8/) for a `reduce` solution